# Dell XPS 15 9500 + Ubuntu audio

Tags: sound, dell, alsa

The audio quality in windows is far superior to what is coming out of my speaks with Ubuntu, I do not have a dualboot.

Have killed pulseaudio and have been playing alsamixer, etc. Nothing helps. If I try hdjackretasker or whatever it is, it will always error that the device is busy no matter what I try

Have tried setting this:
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-laptop - alsa documentation for different models. Nothing in particular for my chips.
options snd-hda-intel probe_mask=0x101

in alsa-base.conf along with numerous other models ive found online, nothing helps. The audio is very "tinny", as if I was listening to it in a tin can.

REALLY hoping someone can recommend something.

```
cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec
Codec: Realtek ALC289
Codec: Intel Kabylake HDMI
have also tried
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0"
```

in /etc/default/grub
any ideas?

Attached is a screenshot of my alsamixers:
[screenshot one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOihl.png) , [screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZff9.png)

Comment: I’ve since done a clean install again and have made a noticeable difference following the notebook speakers tutorial with pulseeffects, but definitely needs some work.

Anyone have any suggestions around pulseffects or other stuff to try?